# Multiple navbars with burger menus on 1 page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 navbars on a page - working fine at non-mobile widths.

The top one has a burger menu - which works fine.

However the burger menu on the second one activates the top burger menu. How can I make it activate it's own burger menu?

Top navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">My Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">My Account</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Welcome John</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Lower navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="midnavbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">My<br />Favourites</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Active<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Passive<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">JJ<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Fund<br />Ranges</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Model<br />Portfolios</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sector<br />Factsheets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Show<br />All</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btnsearch"><i class="glyphicon icon-search"></i></button>                          
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't find anything about this on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

target="#navbar_main"  as  id="navbar_main" to work fine in mobile dives work on id base.

see the demo

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top_navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="top_navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">My Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Our Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">My Account</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Welcome John</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="midnavbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_main" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar_main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">My<br />Favourites</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Active<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Passive<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">JJ<br />Funds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Fund<br />Ranges</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Model<br />Portfolios</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sector<br />Factsheets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Show<br />All</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btnsearch"><i class="glyphicon icon-search"></i></button>                          
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```